# how regex string response from urllib2

Tags: python

i want Regex response from urllib2 request, when i received response i get this string

```
<span title="decrypted md5 hash">abc123</span>
```

my regex test don't work with

> ^ Starts with
>   $ Ends with

here my test code

```
uva = re.search(r'^decrypted md5 hash.$</span>', resultado)
```

i got this error

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xcb' in file md5decode.py on line 13, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: What is line 13 in `md5decode.py`?

Comment: Did you had a look at that link ?

Comment: @Selcuk line 13 is the code shown above

Comment: @MauriceMeyer yes, but i don't know why my encoding not work

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to use the `ASCII` encoding, but the pound symbol is not an ASCII character. Try using UTF-8 encoding. You can start by putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `# coding: utf8` to the very top of your python script should take care of that encoding error, but at the same time, I don't think your regex is doing what you want it to be doing. :)